# C++ - Verifying correct input type

Tags: c++, input

I've got the following piece of code:

```
...
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
cin >> x >> y;
if (x == -1 && y == -1) {
    cout << "exit!";
}
else {
    doSomething();
}
...
```

And it works, but only if I enter 2 numbers. If I were to enter a letter, like 'n', the program gets thrown into an infinite loop. How do I check to make sure the user entered a number and avoid the infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. It doesn't work if you x ou y to 'n' ? At the end 'n' is also a number so it's strange. 2sd think how can you have an infinite loop if there is no loop in your code ?

Comment: When I run the program, I'm supposed to enter 2 numbers separated by a space (x and y), but if I were to enter anything else, like a letter, the program goes into an infinite loop. That's why I'm trying to verify the input, to make sure that the user enters two numbers and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `cin` sees a type disagreement between the input data and the variables you're trying to read into, it enters a "fail" state. The conflicting variables won't be updated. Observe:

```
2010-02-27 22:54:27 ~/tmp/ $ cat ju3.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int             x = 0;
  int             y = 12345;
  string          s, a;

  printf("cin good? %d, reading...\n", cin.good());
  cin >> a >> x >> y >> s;
  printf("a=%s, x=%d, y=%d, s=%s\n", a.c_str(), x, y, s.c_str());
  printf("... read, cin good? %d\n", cin.good());
  return 0;
}
2010-02-27 22:54:36 ~/tmp/ $ g++ ju3.cpp -o ju3
2010-02-27 22:54:56 ~/tmp/ $ echo 1 2 3 4 | ./ju3
cin good? 1, reading...
a=1, x=2, y=3, s=4
... read, cin good? 1
2010-02-27 22:55:05 ~/tmp/ $ echo a x y z | ./ju3
cin good? 1, reading...
a=a, x=0, y=12345, s=
... read, cin good? 0
```

There are two ways to avoid the problem you're seeing.

- The quick-and-dirty solution is to just check `cin.good()` instead of comparing the numbers to `-1`.
- If you want `cin` to behave more robustly, read into `string`s instead of `int`s, and manually verify that they contain only numeric characters. You can then use `stringstream` to easily convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: OK, so I'm using cin >> x >> y to read into strings instead of ints now, but how do I verify that the strings contain only numeric characters? the string class doesn't have an isdigit() function and looping over each letter in the string and trying to call isdigit() on that doesn't work either.

Comment: Like Yin Zhu said, look at the ctype.h header (or the C++ equivalent, called cctype). You'll need to check each letter individually. If your code doesn't work the way you expect it to, use printf to find out why!

Answer (score 0):

input two strings and use functions in `ctype.h` to check the validity of the input.